# Multiple forms on the same view (asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to make a Wizard registration form (multistep registration) in asp.net mvc.

I have 2 methods on my controller (Login and Register) because I dont want that the URL changes.

Well, in the first page (Login) I have 2 forms (Login and registerStep1).

I dont know how to distinguish between the forms in my controller.

I've tried with the name of the button, but I DONT KNOW WHY it just works on chrome.

Firefox gets the correct name of the login button, but give me null value when I try with register button. I really dont know why. Both forms have the same structure.

Register form:

```
model Project.ViewModels.LoginViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <span class="field-validation-error">&nbsp;@ViewBag.RegisterError</span>

    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Step1.Email, new { @class = "noround input-block-level", placeholder = "Your Email" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Step1.Email)
        <small>&nbsp;</small>
    </p>
    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Step1.Document, new { @class = "noround input-block-level", placeholder = "Your document" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Step1.Document)
        <small>&nbsp;</small>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button type="submit" name="buttonName" value="Register" class="noround btn">CONTINUE</button>
    </p>
}
```

The login form is the same but with email and password.

and my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string buttonName)
        {
            if (buttonName == "Register")
            {   
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    bool isValid = true;

                    if (!IsUniqueEmail(model.Step1.Email))
                    {
                        isValid = false;
                    }

                    if (!IsUniqueCPF(model.Step1.Document))
                    { 
                    isValid = false;
                    }

                    if (isValid)
                    {
                        TempData["WizardModel"] = model;
                        return RedirectToAction("Register");
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (buttonName == "Login")
            {
..//the rest
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an:

```
<input type="hidden" name="buttonName" value="Register">
```

in the form.
It works for me in any browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" name="buttonName" value="Login" class="noround btn">Login</button
```

Add login button on page

> make same fields for Register and for Login

and with the use of jquery on login button click submit your form with your button name

Comment: I already have a login button on page. It posts to the same method that register on my controller (Login). Login works fine in any browser. Just the register button that gives me null everytime in Firefox. I was avoiding submit my forms with jQuery, but I will give it a try

Comment: Well, Im really newbie in web but, I need a redirect after submit (From login to Register) I can achieve this with only jquery?